# If radio button is selected, change list of link_to paths in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, conditional-statements

I have a list of `link_to`s like this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Carpooling", offers_path(:category => {:category => "Carpooling"}) %></li>
<li> <%= link_to "Tutoring", offers_path(:category => {:category => "Tutoring"}) %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Studying", offers_path(:category => {:category => "Studying"}) %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Career", offers_path(:category => {:category => "Career"}) %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Art", offers_path(:category => {:category => "Art"}) %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Culture", offers_path(:category => {:category => "Culture"}) %></li>
```

I would like to have two radio buttons, one called Offers and one called Requests. If the Requests radio button is selected, I'd like the paths to change to `requests_path...`. If the Offers radio button is selected, I'd like the paths to stay as they are.

I haven't coded radio buttons before, so am not sure where to start. I'm thinking I'll be using the `radio_button_tag` helper, or should I make this into a form and use `f.radio_button`? My main problem is figuring out the conditional statement. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`polymorphic_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_path) to route to the 'index' action for different resources, without needing to hardcode a method name.

```
<li><%= link_to "Carpooling", polymorphic_path(params[:selected_resource], :category => {:category => "Carpooling"}) %></li>
```

where `params[:selected_resource]` matches the name of your radio input, and the values of that input are either "requests" or "offers"

Comment: Hey, I tried this, but I'm getting the error `Nil location provided. Can't build URI.`. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: Probably `params[:selected_resource]` is `nil`. You might want to consider setting an instance variable in your controller and setting it to a reasonable default if nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the set of links to change dynamically, as in the page loads, and the user can opt to select Requests or Offers.  If that's the case, I'll give you the basic approach here, and I'm confident you can take it from there.

First, the radio buttons are client-side elements, which are interacted with after the page has been rendered for the user.  So, any rails helpers et al will no longer be useful here.  So, to accomplish this conditional logic, you'll need the help of client-side coding, or more specifically, javascript via jQuery.

There are many approaches you can take here, but here's a quick one that I would recommend.

First, draw ALL the elements that you want to appear on the page, like so:

```
<%= link_to "Text 1", my_path, :class => 'link request_link' %>
<%= link_to "Text 2", my_path, :class => 'link offer_link' %>
```

This will yield HTML like:

```
<a class="link request_link" href="/my_path">Text 1</a>
<a class="link offer_link" href="/my_path">Text 2</a>
```

For the radio buttons, you can use form_for or radio_button_tag, really doesn't matter, but the resulting HTML you want will look something like:

```
<input class="link_selector" type="radio" name="link_selector" value="request_link" />
<input class="link_selector" type="radio" name="link_selector" value="offer_link" />
```

Notice that the value for the radio button matches the class name of the link, and the class name for the buttons is link_selector.  The approach here will be to add a listener to the link_selector radio buttons such that when one is selected:

- Grab the value of the selected radio button
- Hide the link elements
- Show the links where the class == the value of the selected radio button.

Some pseudo-code:

```
//This happens when the page is ready
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //Hide all links
  $(".link").hide();

  //Add a listener to the radio buttons
  $(".link_selector").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val()
    $(".link").hide();      //Hide all links
    $("." + value).show();  //Show the appropriate links
  });

  //Optionally, pre-select one of the radio buttons at this point, which 
  //should trigger the listener to show the proper links; otherwise, no 
  //links will appear when the page initially loads.
});
```

Again, there are many ways to accomplish this, but the takeaway here is that you'll need to use javascript to do it.

Hope that helps!